# Pandas: Rolling average starts again on new Multi-Index value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                   'Date':list(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', periods=8)),
                   'Score':[7,3,3,6,7,3,7,5],
                  }).set_index(['Team', 'Date'])
```

I want to add a rolling average column that resets when the Level 0 index is a new value.  The below simple code doesn't work as the rolling average carries over between index values:

```
df['Avg'] = df['Score'].rolling(window=2).mean()


                 Score  Avg
Team Date                  
A    2021-01-01      7  NaN
     2021-01-02      3  5.0
     2021-01-03      3  3.0
     2021-01-04      6  4.5
B    2021-01-05      7  6.5
     2021-01-06      3  5.0
     2021-01-07      7  5.0
     2021-01-08      5  6.0
```

How can I get the below Dataframe?:

```
                 Score  Avg
Team Date                  
A    2021-01-01      7  NaN
     2021-01-02      3  5.0
     2021-01-03      3  3.0
     2021-01-04      6  4.5
B    2021-01-05      7  NaN
     2021-01-06      3  5.0
     2021-01-07      7  5.0
     2021-01-08      5  6.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.group_by`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) (and [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) when assigning to the new column):

```
df['Avg'] = df.groupby('Team').rolling(window=2).mean().values
```

produces

```
                 Score  Avg
Team Date                  
A    2021-01-01      7  NaN
     2021-01-02      3  5.0
     2021-01-03      3  3.0
     2021-01-04      6  4.5
B    2021-01-05      7  NaN
     2021-01-06      3  5.0
     2021-01-07      7  5.0
     2021-01-08      5  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby rolling mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html#pandas-core-window-rolling-rolling-mean) on `level='Team'` and [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) to align the index correctly:

```
df['Avg'] = (
    df.groupby(level='Team')['Score'].rolling(window=2).mean().droplevel(0)
)
```

`df`:

```
                 Score  Avg
Team Date                  
A    2021-01-01      7  NaN
     2021-01-02      3  5.0
     2021-01-03      3  3.0
     2021-01-04      6  4.5
B    2021-01-05      7  NaN
     2021-01-06      3  5.0
     2021-01-07      7  5.0
     2021-01-08      5  6.0
```

---

Benefits of `droplevel` over using `values` is that the index will align correctly.

Given an unordered DataFrame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                   'Date': list(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', periods=8)),
                   'Score': [7, 7, 7, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                   }).set_index(['Team', 'Date'])
```

`df`:

```
                 Score
Team Date             
B    2021-01-01      7
     2021-01-02      7
     2021-01-03      7
     2021-01-04      8
A    2021-01-05      1
     2021-01-06      2
     2021-01-07      1
     2021-01-08      2
```

Notice the difference between `droplevel` and `values`:

```
df['drop_level'] = (
    df.groupby(level='Team')['Score'].rolling(window=2).mean().droplevel(0)
)
df['values'] = (
    df.groupby(level='Team')['Score'].rolling(window=2).mean().values
)
```

```
                 Score  drop_level  values
Team Date                                 
B    2021-01-01      7         NaN     NaN
     2021-01-02      7         7.0     1.5
     2021-01-03      7         7.0     1.5
     2021-01-04      8         7.5     1.5  # These are the averages from A
A    2021-01-05      1         NaN     NaN
     2021-01-06      2         1.5     7.0  # These are the averages from B
     2021-01-07      1         1.5     7.0
     2021-01-08      2         1.5     7.5
```